# WordPress translation providing string translation

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am working on WordPress project and I want to provide translation in my own mother language as well like (URDU). I have installed `.pot, .po and .mo` files very well and its working for me fine. Now, the problem is that, in all strings which I want to replace, will I be providing translation messages for all those strings ? If, yes. Then it will take my million hours due to huge content, how to do that in any smaller or easier way ??? Any hints or references will be appreciated ...

Comment: I am working on the same thing but i think we don't have any solution rather than translate whole content.

Comment: that's not a better choice if we have 10000 different strings ... or what about if we want to translate in more than 50 languages ??? There should must be any such thing to do for us ??? Any one who knows that magic ???

Comment: The magic that you are looking for is (human or machine) translation. A professional human translator can translate between 1000 and 2500 words per day. This includes term research, queries, terminology management, etc. If you need 50 target languages you may want to contact a multi-language agency, unless you want to communicate with 50 translators. Machine translation engines will be faster: try it for Urdu and see if the results are good enough.

Answer (score 0):

1) The usual solution is translate only the strings which are displayed in the frontend.

2) The other thing is to join some huge Translation Memory (TM) for your language and get the strings from there, but if you're not a translator yourself, it will be hard/impossible to find. [Pro version of Poedit](https://poedit.net/pro) gives you access to its TM (users can share), but nobody knows if there will be something for you.

3) If you want to provide complete translation, you have to do it yourself (manually) or find a translator with webpage specialisation and some software which allows you to use your TM and translate .po files as well (at least, Trados does it)

I would write in comments, but its too long.
Hope it helps at least a little bit.